# Restoring old MySQL database settings

Tags: mysql, windows, restore

I know this question may be similar to some others posted but think it may be slightly different, so hopefully it's ok.

Basically I just reinstalled `Windows` as I bought a new HD and I am in the process of copying all the MySQL databases back to the new installation dir; however I'm not sure if it's ok to copy all the default MySQL databases back with it? Those being:

- cdcol
- mysql
- performance_schema
- phpmyadmin
- test
- webauth

I assume one of these contain details I want to keep such as info about the users and also other stuff like mysql variables - unless that is found in a MySQL `.ini` file or something?

I'm not 100% sure but I'm pretty sure I'm still using the same version of MySQL. If it matters I am using XAMPP.

So basically my question is can I copy the old folders above over the new ones and what are these folders/databases used for exactly (other than the obvious phpmyadmin one)?

Comment: What version of MySQL did you install, and were you using MyISAM or InnoDB for your tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say on the new server you want datadir to be `D:\MySQLData`

Simply copy everything and all subfolders from old server's `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data` to the new server's `D:\MySQLData`. You said you are using XAMPP. RUn this query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';`. Copy that folder to `D:\MySQLData`.

Then add this

```
[mysqld]
datadir="D:/MySQLData"
```

in the new server's `my.ini`

This will work seamlessly if the new server has the same version of MySQL as the old.

If the new server has the next higher major release (5.1 -> 5.5,5.5 - > 5.6) you will then have to run `mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables`. Make sure you keep a backup.

If you are using InnoDB (in whole or in part), get all the InnoDB settings from the old `my.ini` over the new server's `my.ini`.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Caveat, stop the MySQL server before moving files around.